# Select specific count of numbers after a specific character from excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a situation with a automatically exported excel file. In one of the cells there is a Client_ID which is situated among a lot of other characters(also numbers). The ID is either after the phrase "Client_ID=" or after the phrase "Telesales=". Before and after the phrase there are other characters. Also both of the phrases could appear in the cell. Here is an exapmple of the content of the cell:

> sys_CHSID=1487626|sys_StatConversationID=100001624765|sys_ANI=00889620663|sys_DNIS=9800|sys_REDIR=600|sys_Entrytime=1568721995|sys_ConversationID=191000930271|sys_CaseID=Customer
>   Service|Client_ID=8813262350|Menu=1.1 - Remaining
>   installments|Topic=Customer
>   Service|sys_Prio=10|sys_Skill=Service|sys_ACW=3|sys_RouteStartTime=1568722038|sys_CS_Marker=VQ_Waiting_for_Operator_CS|Waited=0
>   seconds|Agent=b041|Firstname=Antoa|Lastname=Ilie|Recording_1=612_1_20190917150721_140|Telesales=test
>   10 000Р»РІ РїРѕС‚СЉСЂСЃРµС‚Рµ РіРѕ СѓС‚СЂРµ СЃР»РµРґ 15С‡

I've tried so far with:

`=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};(MID(A1;(FIND("CLIENT_ID=";A1;1)>0);10))))>5;MID(A1;(FIND("CLIENT_ID=";A1;1)+4);10);MID(A1;(FIND("Telesales=";A1;1)+10);10))`

but does not working due to the fact that there are numbers which are not Client_ID after "Telesales=".

Comment: What are you trying to extract?

Comment: The 10 digits after "Client_ID=" (8813262350 in the example)

Comment: And you're looking for a formula rather than VBA solution? What happens if both bits of text appear - will only one have a number after it?

Comment: Not necessary. After "Client_ID=" if exists, or if there is anything after it - it will be what I am looking for. After the second phrase it could be anything. And yes, I prefer excel formula.

Comment: Would both `Client_ID` and `Telesales=` always be in the string with only one of them actually containing a valid 10 digit ID?

Comment: One of them always contain the valid ID, but any one of them could be missing. It's a foking disaster. I'll try to change the settings in the system from which there are exported, but it'll take longer time.

Comment: You might want to post a few more examples, stripping out extraneous text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("Client_ID=",A1,1)+10,10),MID(A1,FIND("Telesales=",A1,1)+10,10))`

If you need to check the ID:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A1,FIND("Client_ID=",A1,1)+10,10))=FALSE,IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("Client_ID=",A1,1)+10,10),MID(A1,FIND("Telesales=",A1,1)+10,10)))`

Hope it helps

Comment: I am understanding that you are looking first for `Client_ID` and if it fails, for `Telesales`

Comment: Yep. But after "Client_ID=" could be nothing , or other characters. I want somehow to validate that "MID(A1,FIND("Client_ID=",A1,1)+10,10" is selecting 10 digits only numbers.

Comment: Have you got always 10 numbers (if there are numbers)?

Comment: If it is a valid ID - it is always 10 numbers. Sometime, like in the example it could be text and some numbers(Telesales=test10 000Р)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ID number is always separated by "|" like in the case above, this formula should work:

edit: seems to be answered already, but this one works for any length of ID.

```
IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1;FIND("Client_ID";A1)+10;1)));MID(A1;FIND("Client_ID";A1)+10;FIND("|";A1;FIND("Client_ID";A1))-(FIND("Client_ID";A1)+10));MID(A1;FIND("Telesales";A1)+10;FIND("|";A1;FIND("Telesales";A1))-(FIND("Telesales";A1)+10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("Client_ID=",A1)),ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("Client_ID=",A1)+10,10)))),MID(A1,FIND("Client_ID=",A1)+10,10),MID(A1,FIND("Telesales=",A1)+10,10))
```